# Can you use chinese remainder theorum to convert hex to dec in your head?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, chinese-remainder-theorem

At one time I was able to convert hex to decimal in my head, using a trick I learned in college. I have not used it in years,  and forgot how. 
Does anyone remember how to use the Chinese remainder theorem to convert hex to decimal quickly?